Como faço pro meu vídeo começar o play somente quando a pessoa clica pra abrir o modal?
Boa tarde! Inseri um vídeo no meu site com um modal para quando clicarem no play abrir uma janela e o vídeo iniciar. Mas o vídeo começa a rodar assim que entram na página e, com isso, a música do vídeo fica tocando, mesmo sem clicarem para dar o play. Como resolvo isso?
Tentei retirar as tags de autoplay e mesmo assim o vídeo continua iniciando junto com a abertura da página. Tenho outros vídeos na página e tirei também as tags de autoplay deles, mesmo problema.
Será que preciso retirar do iframe? Pelo que pesquisei ele deixa meio limitado, mas sem ele não consegui inserir os vídeos no modal.
Desde já, obrigado!
Meu código é esse:
<section class="mi-feature py-4 ">
              <div class="container">
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col p-0 p-lg-1 m-2 m-lg-auto rounded" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;"> <!-- customização precisa ser a partir daqui-->
                          <div class="row g-3 p-3 d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row align-items-start align-items-lg-center" >
                                <div class="col p-1 p-lg-auto ps-lg-5 btn" onclick="abrirvideo5()">
                                  <img class="shadow" src="./assets/images/mockup-tela-video-apresentacao-sigalite.jpg" width="100%" alt="">
                                </div>
                              <div class="col p-2 p-lg-auto ps-lg-5">
                                  <h3 class="pb-2 pb-lg-3">A solução ideal para pequenos comércios</h3>
                                  <p>Confira nosso vídeo e descubra porque o Milersoft Siga Lite pode ser a solução ideal para o seu negócio!</p>
                              </div>
                              <div class="janela-video5" id="janela-video5">
                                <div class="video5">
                                    <button class="fechar" id="fechar">X</button>
                                    <iframe allow=autoplay autoplay=1 width="1000" height="563" src="./assets/videos/Apresentacao_SigaLite.mp4" type="video/mp4"></iframe>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </section>

    <style>
      .centered-text {
         text-align: center;
      }

      .janela-video5{
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #00000085;
        display: none;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        z-index: 999;
      }

      .video5{
          display:flex;
          align-items:center;
          justify-content: center;
          position: relative;
          /*width: 80%;
          min-width: 450px;
          min-height: 200px;*/
          background-color: #ffffff;
          padding: 20px;
          border-radius: 20px;
      }

      .fechar{
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
          position: absolute;
          top: -15px;
          right: -15px;
          width: 30px;
          height: 30px;
          border-radius: 50%;
          border: solid 1px grey;
          background-color: white;
          color: #212529;
          font-size: 15px;
          cursor: pointer;
      }

      .janela-video5.abrir{
          display: flex;
      }

      @keyframes abrirvideo5 {
          from{
              opacity: 0;
              transform: translate3d(0, -20px, 0);
          }
          to{
              opacity: 1;
              transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
          }
          
      }

      .abrir .video5{
          animation: abrirvideo5 0.5s;
      }

    </style>

    <script src="script-abrir-video5.js"></script>

function abrirvideo5(){
    console.log('aqui')
    const video5 = document.getElementById('janela-video5')
    video5.classList.add('abrir')

    video5.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if(e.target.id == 'fechar' || e.target.id == 'janela-video5'){
            video5.classList.remove('abrir')
        }
    })
}

